# How to remove billing details from woocommerce emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to remove billing details from Woocoommerce's emails, is there any other way to do this besides editing all email templates?

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by filtering [`woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/faaac6d67bfa644abc0d66034df7932987b53801/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L428):

```
function so_43549371_remove_billing_fields_from_emails( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    if( isset( $fields['billing_email'] ) ){
        unset( $fields['billing_email'] );
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'so_43549371_remove_billing_fields_from_emails', 10, 3 );
```

This will remove the billing email only from all emails, but I passed the extra `$sent_to_admin` and `$order` parameters if you want to only do that under certain conditions.

This will remove all the customer details entirely:

```
function so_43549371_remove_customer_details() {
    $mailer = WC()->mailer();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', array( $mailer, 'customer_details' ), 10, 3 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'so_43549371_remove_customer_details' );
```

Comment: You're right, this doesn't seem to do anything because I made an error on the array keys in the `$fields` array. Can you elaborate which fields you want to remove?

Comment: @helgatheviking so how do we remove billing information from the email that the shop admin receive? I want to do this to avoid shipping items to their billing address

Comment: @Houstonwehaveaproblem i'd probably use the first snippet and test `if( $sent_to_admin )` and then unset all the shipping fields... shipping_address, shipping_address2, shipping_city etc.